# Bootstrap navi flickering by scrolling after clicking to a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a fixed to top navigation. I have this navi from Bootstrap 3. On my page, I have several links, which have an svg image inside. By hovering on the link, it begin to move up and down. When I click to these links, my page scrolls smooth down to a specific position. But when I am trying to scroll down or up after clicking to those links, my navigation starts flickering in chrome. But when I click anywhere on the page with the mouse, it stops flickering.

What could be the problem or how to emulate a mouseclick anywhere on the page?

I tried:

```
$('body').click();
```

But it did now work.

Here is my site:
http://mival.de/examples/mival/index.html

When u click on the black arrow and scroll after the page in chrome, the navi start flickering.

**JS Scroll**

```
//jQuery to collapse the navbar on scroll
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(".navbar").offset().top > 50) {
        $(".navbar-fixed-top").addClass("top-nav-collapse");
    } else {
        $(".navbar-fixed-top").removeClass("top-nav-collapse");
    }
});

//jQuery for page scrolling feature - requires jQuery Easing plugin
$(function() {
    $('a.page-scroll').bind('click', function(event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
        event.preventDefault();
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#homeSection').click();
        }, 500);
    });

});
```

Comment: Could you provide us a working sample?

Comment: Yeah, here is the example. http://mival.de/examples/mival/index.html When u click on the down arrow and then u scroll down the page in chrome, the navi starts to flicker.

Comment: It's an interesting problem. I can't spot the problem. So emulating the `$('body').click();` didn't work. I know that's not ideal since it's a work around.

Comment: Ok, I found out, that it appears because the animation by hovering the arrow. After I had deleted this animation from my stylesheet, everything began to work.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found the solution. just added the following, to my arrow:hover class:

```
 -webkit-perspective: 1000;
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
```

Do not really know, what it do, but it works!

P.S.: Besides that, I changed the measure of my translateY rule from em to px.